# C# Find a variable by value

Tags: c#

I am making an "error code to String" converter that would display the name of an error code from its value, for example `0x000000c3` would give `"Class not found"`, but using MY OWN error codes!

Here's how it actually looks like:

```
#region errcodes
    public int NORMAL_STOP      = 0x00000000;
    public int LIB_BROKEN       = 0x000000a1;
    public int RESOURCE_MISSING = 0x000000a2;
    public int METHOD_NOT_FOUND = 0x000000a3;
    public int FRAMEWORK_ERROR  = 0x000000b1;
    public int UNKNOWN          = 0x000000ff;
#endregion
    public string getName(int CODE)
    {

    }
```

I would like to get a `string` value from parameter `CODE`, in function `getName`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you looked into using an enum?

Comment: C# is not C, C++ or Java: please don't use `UPPER_CASE` identifiers. If you use an `enum` you can get the enum value's identifier simply by calling `.ToString()` though for localisation I suggest you use the Resources functionality and use the enum as a key.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This way, the index of the value is the same as the error code ! Thanks !

Comment: @Dai OK ! ^^
Now I would like one of you two to write his comment as an answer for me to close the question please !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good C# practice is using of an enum:

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
    NORMAL_STOP      = 0x00000000,
    LIB_BROKEN       = 0x000000a1,
    RESOURCE_MISSING = 0x000000a2,
    METHOD_NOT_FOUND = 0x000000a3,
    FRAMEWORK_ERROR  = 0x000000b1,
    UNKNOWN          = 0x000000ff
}

public const string InvalidErrorCodeMessage = "Class not found";

public static string GetName(ErrorCode code)
{
    var isExist = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ErrorCode), code);
    return isExist ? code.ToString() : InvalidErrorCodeMessage;
}

public static string GetName(int code)
{
    return GetName((ErrorCode)code);
}
```

Another good advice: it would be great to use the C# naming convention for error codes:

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
    NormalStop      = 0x00000000,
    LibBroken       = 0x000000a1,
    ResourceMissing = 0x000000a2,
    MethodNotFound  = 0x000000a3,
    FrameworkError  = 0x000000b1,
    Unknown         = 0x000000ff
}
```

Usage example:

```
void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine(GetName(0)); // NormalStop
  Console.WriteLine(GetName(1)); // Class not found
  Console.WriteLine(GetName(ErrorCode.Unknown)); // Unknown
}
```

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question. The OP wants to know how to get the ErrorCode Enum name from the assigned value.  EG, how to get NormalStop from 0x00......

Comment: @DarrenYoung, the GetName method returns name of the given code.

Comment: As far as I understand the OP wants to pass in a string such as '0x000..." and get back the ErrorCode, eg NormalStop.  Taken from the question "for example 0x000000c3 would give "Class not found"

Comment: @DarrenYoung No, i think not.

Comment: @DarrenYoung, Ok, I added an int overload for the GetName method.

Comment: @DarrenYoung yes, but as I noticed it was pointless, I marked the answer as solution to close the post.